# How to get "usr_paths" field?

Tags: java, websphere

```
java.lang.reflect.Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
field.setAccessible(true);
String[] paths = (String[])field.get(null);
```

When use Tomcat, I can get 'java.library.path'. But When use IBM WebSphere, don't work.
Designation of property is wrong?

Add:

```
ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

I cannot find "usr_paths".

Comment: do you get any exception/error? or does it just not return anything? also any security concerns you should worry about?

Comment: i think you might be running into problems due to the Tomcat vs. WebSphere JVM interaction (and/or security problems: maybe your server does not have sufficient permissions or something like that to access the JVM)

Comment: Also, as stated in this link (http://nicklothian.com/blog/2008/11/19/modify-javalibrarypath-at-runtime/) and other relevant places where this code shows up when searching, this might not be portable on all platforms either

Answer (score 1):

As i noted in the comments, this problem can be the result of one of two (or more) possible reasons (or a combination): 
- you are running into security/permission issues with WebSphere
- the code you are writing might not really be portable on all plaforms, JVMs

I would advise to look into these possible directions.

Hope this helps.